# Why didn't Qui-Gon Jin's body "vanish" after his death?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

I was wondering whether there is an explanation why Qui-Gon's body does not vanish right away after he is killed by Darth Maul!? Obi-Wan's and Yoda's bodies vanish right away, while Qui-Gon's is burned at a funeral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qui-Gon's body didn't vanish because at that point, Jedi didn't know the skill *to be the one with force* (If you take *Legends* into account, the skill was lost).

Later in Episode 3, Qui-Gon's force ghost learned/re-discovered that skill and told it Yoda. Yoda taught that to Obi-Wan. That's why both were able to vanish at the time of their death (you should note that Obi-Wan's body vanished before Vader's lightsaber touched his body).