# How was it that Qui-Gon was able to become one with the Force?

Tags: star-wars

When I read [Why didn't Qui-Gon Jin's body "vanish" after his death?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84997/why-didnt-qui-gon-jins-body-vanish-after-his-death) I wondered about one thing:

- He died and his body did NOT disappear
- The skill for becoming one with the Force was lost for a long time (Legends and at least to some extent also Disney canon as the skill was unknown to both Jedi and Sith seemingly)
- If someone dies without having this skill he merges with the Force and his personality is lost,.... (as the skill saves the personality of theirs)

So as Qui-Gon died without having the skill and no one was able to teach him like it was with Anakin, is there any explanation on HOW he was able to acquire it and save his personality?

(primarily looking for canon answers)

Comment: I reckon this is somehow explained in Clone Wars series 6.

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware that is why I ask (Only explained there how Yoda got the skill not how Qui gon got it as far as I know)

Comment: Darth Vader and Yoda's bodies didn't vanish either.  Only Obiwans. *"Plot Inconsistencies are strong in this one"*

Comment: Are you sure? Yodas body did vanish in the original version as far as I remember star wars 6 back from when it ran in cinema! And as for Vader: We dont see what happens with his body only with his armor (which is dark side infused anyway)

Comment: In ROTJ, Yoda's body did disappear upon his death: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id-9qT8bEL8 (at the 5:37 mark)

Comment: It appears that Qui-gon was intently preparing for his own potential death by meditating before his final fight with Darth Maul.

Comment: @Benxamin where do you have this info from?

Comment: Not sure if TPM is considered canon, but it's right there in the movie [this clip 2:05-2:25](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHqdESArkqU&start=125). From the first time I saw this, I thought it odd that in the middle of a fight, he trades any advantage of readiness for a meditation pose. And for what? A clear mind & centered state of calm? There must be something else he's doing... There are no other obvious Force effects. I argue that when Jedi meditate, they are active in the Force. Do you recall Luke handstanding and floating rocks in TESB? Same thing: body still, huge Force activity.

Comment: @Benxamin I always thought that that part was just him doing something during the time he had to wait.....when it was time to stand and act again he would feel through the force anyway. So him meditating and maul walking around aggressively and attacking the bars I only saw as killing time and apointing out the difference between how sith and jedi act

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is much on it, but it looks like Qui-Gon learned the skill from the [Ancient Order of the Whills](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Order_of_the_Whills) from the Episode III Script.

> "The secret of the Ancient Order of the Whills, he studied." - Yoda

So there is some reference to Qui-Gon possessing the skill prior to becoming one with the Force, or known as becoming a ["Force Ghost"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_ghost).

[Some Additional Information on the Ancient Order of the Whills](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38199/what-are-the-journals-of-the-whills)

Comment: Could you support your answer with quotes or any other canon material?

Comment: Added the quote from the script, but other than that I have no more material on it, sorry =(

Comment: Thanks! also in the question you linked to there is an indication why qui gon was leaving his body behind (he had the training but was not fully ready).